# SBT - why sbt giving compilation errors while running?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to merge two modules into single module. Both are successfully running modules. I merge two modules. And trying to run the test cases.
i am compiling source and testcases by using sbt commands:

```
sbt
clean
compile
project module-read
test:compile
it:test
```

Till `test:compile` everything working fine but after it:test, it showing lot of compilation issues.

Could I know best way of compiling?

Comment: Please provide the errors that you are facing !

Answer (score 2):

The *test:compile* task will only compile tests within the src/test/scala folder as per the default sbt test configuration.

In order to compile your integration tests (in src/it/scala) you will have to run *it:compile* .

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#integration-tests for more info.

Comment: It is showing errors. thanks @Pascal , so I have to run it:compile.